# EC2 - how to check if device is mounted?

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto

I'm using the python boto library and wrote a script (which runs on an ec2 instance) to get a list of all volumes attached to that instance.

Now I need to check whether each volume is mounted, and if it's mounted, what is the mount point. I thought I would be able to search /proc/mounts for the volume device (using volume.attach_data.device), but that does not work because Amazon renames the devices from something like /dev/sdf to something like /dev/xvda. I have not seen any clear documentation on whether this renaming occurs 100% of the time (regardless of your instance type, volume type, etc.) or how to determine the new device name.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently went through this - renames like this:

sdf -> xvdf, sdg -> xvdg, and so on

It is consistent.
For a longer explanation see this thread:
[How to attach new EBS volume to Ubuntu machine on AWS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47617/how-to-attach-new-ebs-volume-to-ubuntu-machine-on-aws)

So you should be able to use your original idea to check the mount point and just remap the naming.